# Generic Method to return multiple resultsets ado.net

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have the below generic method that works very well in reading 1 resultset.I have been fiddling trying to write a generic method to return multiple resulset
Could you give me a hand or suggestion how I could turn the below one into a method that returns/handle multiple resultset.

usage:

```
const string spName = "GetCountry";
object[] parms = { "@CountryId", countryId };
myDto dto = spName.GetOne(ToDto, parms);
return model;



public static T GetOne<T>(this string spName,
                                           Func<IDataReader, T> createObject,
                                           object[] parms = null)
{
    try
    {

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.CommandText = spName;
                command.SetParameters(parms);

                connection.Open();

                T t = default(T);
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    t = createObject(reader);
                }

                return t;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        etc......
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

an example would be :A customer with Addresses  (SP will return a customer all the related addresses by returning  2 resultsets inside a sp.)
Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Do you mean multiple result *sets* or just multiple results from a *single* set? If the former, are we to assume that all of the result sets return objects of the same *shape* (column names and types) such that they can all be converted to `T`s, or will each set require different types and conversion functions?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I mean Multiple result sets. I mean return A Customer with all the orders .Customer an object and a table and Order is an object and table. the SP will return a single customer with all the orders associated with that customer

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this elegantly?